# Xen PV VM uses max 1 Thread

Tags: multithreading, xen, paravirtualization, vcpu

I am running a CPU benchmark tool (LINPACK) on a PV virtual machine inside Xen 4.5.1 on Ubuntu 15.10 x64 on an IBM x3550 M4 server. This tool should consume all possible CPU cycles available. I allocate 4 vCPUs by defining this in the Xen PV (test.cfg). However, LINPACK detects only 1 core and 4 threads while it should detect at least 4 cores:

```
CPU frequency:    2.494 GHz
Number of CPUs: 1
Number of cores: 1
Number of threads: 4
```

This is what lscpu says inside this Xen PV VM:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    4
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 62
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v2 @ 2.50GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2500.062
BogoMIPS:              5000.12
Hypervisor vendor:     Xen
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              10240K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Other platforms such as Docker and HVM DO get cores allocated inside the virtual node (see below). These nodes have significant better performance then the Xen PV virtual node.

```
CPU frequency:    2.499 GHz
Number of CPUs: 2
Number of cores: 8
Number of threads: 4
```

This is the DomU Xen host machine lscpu:

```
lscpu

Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 62
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v2 @ 2.50GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2500.062
BogoMIPS:              5000.12
Hypervisor vendor:     Xen
Virtualization type:   none
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              10240K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

Xen vCPU list:

```
xl vcpu-list

Domain-0                             0     0    7   -b-      10.1  all / all
Domain-0                             0     1    2   -b-       6.5  all / all
Domain-0                             0     2    4   r--       2.6  all / all
Domain-0                             0     3    0   r--       3.9  all / all
Domain-0                             0     4    3   -b-       4.4  all / all
Domain-0                             0     5    6   -b-       2.6  all / all
Domain-0                             0     6    5   -b-       4.7  all / all
Domain-0                             0     7    7   -b-       2.9  all / all
test                                 3     0    1   -b-       1.5  0-3 / all
test                                 3     1    0   -b-       1.8  0-3 / all
test                                 3     2    0   -b-       0.7  0-3 / all
test                                 3     3    2   -b-       0.6  0-3 / all
```

xen DomU PV VM config:

```
cat test.cfg

bootloader = '/usr/lib/xen-4.5/bin/pygrub'

vcpus   =  '4'
memory  =  '2048'
cpus    = "0-3"
```

Is there any options to give the paravirtualized guest the host-cpu topology? In other words, how do I get Xen to use more vCPU cores/ vCPUs?

Thanks!